# Lentitud con dompdf

Tags: php, pdf

Estoy usando la libreria [DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) para generar una lista de precios. Tuve un detalle para usarla con composer que luego consultaré, pero instalandola de forma tradicional me funcionó bien y pude generar pdfs sin problema. El inconveniente vino al intentar renderizar información desde la base de datos.

Tengo una tabla de productos con menos de 50 registros, realizo la consulta, la traigo y recorro armando el html para el PDF. Si hago la impresión del HTML directo, el mismo se ejecuta en su totalidad en 1 segundo, por decir algo. Pero si intento pasar ese HTML a DOMPDF. la página dura hasta 3 minutos en ejecutarse y en algunas ocaciones tira una pantalla blanca y no crea el archivo PDF. Intenté probando con los ciclos for y foreach. el resultado es el mismo. A continuación coloco el código de mi vista:

```
<!-- Html pure code here-->
<?php for ($i=0; $i < count($products); $i++) { ?>
    <section class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3><?=$products[$i]['codigo']?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h3><?=$products[$i]['titulo']?></h3>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="<?=$products[$i]['img']?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 data-producto">
            <div class="descripcion">
                <?=$products[$i]['descripcion']?>
            </div>
            <div class="precios">
                <span class="precio">

                </span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<?php } ?>
```

Y este el código de mi controlador :

```
$categorias = $this->post('id_categoria');
$productos = new Modelos\Producto();
// This method make the query and return an array with data.
$products = 
    $productos->get(
        ['id_categoria'=>$categorias],
        null,
        'categoria asc,titulo asc'
    );

//Helpers\Debug::imprimir($listadoProductos);
ob_start();
include 'Layout/electron/listado.tpl.php';
$html1 = ob_get_clean();
if (ob_get_length()) ob_end_clean();

$pdf = new Dompdf();
//exit($html1)
$pdf->loadHtml($html1);
$pdf->render();
$pdf->stream();
```

Como les comenté, remuevo la creación del PDF y el código corre rápido y sin problema. Si quito el ciclo for y con esto, la impresión de data traida de base de datos, pero sigo haciendo la consulta. El pdf tambien se genera rápido y sin problema.

¿Que puedo hacer para mejorar esto? Gracias.

Comment: lo más probable es que la estructura en $html1 sea incorrecta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que *DOMPDF* no soporta bootstrap.

**Solución del problema**

No habia error en la estructura del html, tampoco en que usara funcionalidades de buffer para obtenerlo. El problema está en que estaba incluyendo la libreria de bootstrap la cual no es bien soportada por DOMPDF. De hecho, probé incluyendo solo el sistema de grids de bootstap, con lo cual ya se ejecutaba sin problema el pdf pero **tampoco funciona correctamente**. Por tanto, reedite el diseño haciendo un css sólo para el pdf y en el pdf usé tablas donde usaba la estructura de grid.

[Acá el link de mi ticket en github](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1435#event-1078079875)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente: si te exporta rápido significa que tu variable $html1 no tiene el formato correcto y por algún lado le causa problemas al dompdf, puedes hacer un var_dump($html1) y ver la estructura de su html; puedes replicar el html como texto plano y meterlo en una variable php y ver los resultados.

```
$categorias = $this->post('id_categoria');
$productos = new Modelos\Producto();
// This method make the query and return an array with data.
$products =
    $productos->get(
        ['id_categoria'=>$categorias],
        null,
        'categoria asc,titulo asc'
    );

//Helpers\Debug::imprimir($listadoProductos);
$html1='
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Reporte pdf</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mireporte.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th><th>Existencia</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Producto1</td><td>12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Producto2</td><td>3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
';

$pdf = new Dompdf();
//exit($html1)
$pdf->loadHtml($html1);
$pdf->render();
$pdf->stream();
```

Comment: Es lo que le comenté. yo probé pdfs normales, sin bucles y corren rápido. pero mi variable $html1 tiene justo lo que usted ve allí. por eso viene mi consulta, pues yo no veo nada mal. si quito el bucle corre bien.

Comment: y si le pones el html que genera ese bucle corre bien?

Comment: No. es allí donde se tarda. ese es el problema que estoy consultando. allí está el código. si verificas $html1 se llena con el contenido del html que muestro arriba. Lo capturo on el ob_get_clean();. Pero por eso puse el código. como comenté he probado con dos bucles e ignoro que puede estar mal, pues el código solo corre correctamente.

Comment: Entonces el problema no es dompdf, es tu bucle for?

Comment: Es que es eso lo que no entiendo. como te comente, el bucle corre bien. el html se imprime bien. pero efectivamente el bucle es el que está teniendo inconvenientes con el dompdf. solo que no entiendo el por qué. Son pocos registros, o la libreria no acepta ese tipo de inserciones?

Comment: mira amigo la libreria no tiene nada que ver con tu bucle for, ella simplemente procesa lo que tu le envias en la variable $html1 exactamente esta linea $pdf->loadHtml($html1);  mi consulta es, Si es justo esa linea la que tarda en ejecutarse o es antes?

Comment: Entiendo tu comentario amigo. pero de allí viene mi duda. Precisamente es esa línea la que da problema. si ves justo antes, está comentado un exit() que imprime la varibale $html1. si yo lo descomento. llega allí e imprime el html de forma inmediata. sin problemas. Gracias por su colaboración

Comment: solo se me ocurre que la estructura del html esta mal, yo utilizo esta librería para imprimir reportes que hacen hasta 16 consultas a la base de datos y no me ha dado ningún problema, como dije antes, no se si probaste setear manual el codigo html.